# Stick <div> between <li> and <a> WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, menuitem, nav

I have a wordpress greatmag theme on my website. I would like to stick a div wrapper around the anchor tag in the li tag for design purpose. I looked up the php, but not sure how/or where I can create the  tag.

Code below:

```
if ( !function_exists('greatmag_desktop_menu') ) :
function greatmag_desktop_menu() {
    ?>
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default main-navigation bgf6">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <?php if ( function_exists('max_mega_menu_is_enabled') && max_mega_menu_is_enabled('primary') ) : ?>
                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary') );  ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <?php
                        wp_nav_menu( array(
                            'menu'              => 'primary',
                            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                            'container'         => 'div',
                            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker(),
                            'social'            => greatmag_social_login())
                        );
                    ?>
                    <button class="off-canvas-trigger" aria-controls="primary" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    <?php
    do_action('greatmag_before_header');?>
<?php
}
endif;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Probably easiest/best to use javascript to create the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
'before'            => '<div class="menu_wrapper">',
'after'             => '<div>',
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ( !function_exists('greatmag_desktop_menu') ) :
function greatmag_desktop_menu() {
    ?>
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default main-navigation bgf6">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <?php if ( function_exists('max_mega_menu_is_enabled') && max_mega_menu_is_enabled('primary') ) : ?>
                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                             'theme_location' => 'primary',

                              // add before and after args
                             'before' => '<div class=".....">', 
                             'after' => '</div>',
                         ));  ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <?php
                        wp_nav_menu( array(
                            'menu'              => 'primary',
                            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                            'container'         => 'div',
                            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker(),
                            'social'            => greatmag_social_login()),

                            // add before and after args
                            'before'            => '<div class=".....">', 
                            'after'             => '</div>',
                        );
                    ?>
                    <button class="off-canvas-trigger" aria-controls="primary" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    <?php
    do_action('greatmag_before_header');?>
<?php
}
endif;
```